# How Can I Proxy A Referenced Entity Before Saving?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.0 along with Spring Data JPA and Spring MVC. I have the following 2 entities:

**Country.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "country_name" , nullable = false , length = 50)
    @NotNull @Size(max = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "country_acronym" , length = 3)
    @Size(max = 3)
    private String acronym;

    //Getters-Setters
    //Equals-Hashcode (determines equality based only on name attribute)
}
```

**City.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "city_name")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_country")
    private Country country;

    //Getters-Setters
    //Equals/Hashcode (all attributes)
}
```

What I want to achieve is to save cities through REST calls. One catch is that I want in the body of the request to provide only the name of the country and if that country exists in the countries table, then it must be able to find the reference by itself , else it should first insert a new country and then match the reference.

For complete reference, let me provide the Repository and Controller classes:

**CityRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City,Integer>
{
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
@RestController
public class MainController
{

    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/countries")
    private void insertCountry(@RequestBody @Valid Country country)
    {
        countryRepository.save(country);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/cities")
    public void insertCities(@RequestBody @Valid City city)
    {
        cityRepository.save(city);
    }
}
```

A sample body of a request:

```
{
    "name": "Nikaia",
    "country": {
        "name": "Greece"
    }
}
```

The error I get is that Hibernate always tries to save the country, it never looks if it exists (I get a constraint violation). I guess that the country never gets proxied by Hibernate because it isn't yet a persisted entity. Is there a way I can easily solve that using Data JPA ? Or should I go a level lower and play with the EntityManager? Complete code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's logical. For your desire feature fetch the country by country name. If exist then set that in city object.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/cities")
public void insertCities(@RequestBody @Valid City city)
{
    Country country = countryRepository.findByName(city.getCountry().getName());
    if(country  != null) city.setCountry(country);
    cityRepository.save(city);
}
```

And `findByName` in `CountryRepository` also

```
Country  findByName(String name);
```

Comment: I imagined that solution but in more complex situations, that would create lot's of boilerplate code. I was looking for a way for the process to be more automated. However, if something better doesn't show up , I'll accept the answer.

Comment: How spring automatically understand fetch country by country name? So it's needed to fetch and set.